# Display date and time into post edit comments section

Tags: comments, date

My users need to see the date and time for each comment from the post edit page. Can anyone help me to display these metadata please?

Edit: When editing a post (cpt in my case) you can see the comments related to it and create new comments or answers. But the comments metabox only display username, email, IP, and comments content. I would like the date and time to be displayed for each comments, as it is already enabled in the front end or in the admin comments section.

Better with a picture maybe :

[image]

Sorry for my poor english...

Comment: You can display meta data by packing the php in short code and then add the short code everywhere. * Please add more info to question for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer given by [Ferman](https://wpfr.net/support/utilisateurs/ferman/) on [wpfr.net](https://wpfr.net/support/sujet/afficher-la-date-et-heure-des-commentaire-dans-la-page-dedition-des-articles/#post-2362636)

```
function date_commentaire( ){

$comments = get_comments( array( 'post_id' => get_the_ID() ));

if ( doing_action( 'wp_ajax_get-comments' ) )                   
    foreach ( $comments as $comment ) : 
    $a = $comment->comment_ID;
    $b = get_comment_ID();
    $date_comment = get_comment_date();
    $time_comment = get_comment_time();

if ( $a==$b )       
    echo '<p class="commentaire-date">'.'Commentaire N°:   '.$comment->comment_ID.'   du:    '.$date_comment.' à '.$time_comment.'</p>';
    endforeach; 
    
return $comment_author_url; 
}
add_filter( 'get_comment_author_url','date_commentaire');
```

Works great. I just pasted it into functions.php child theme instead of using the advised plugin.